# C# Xamarin Forms Items not set in a Grouped ListView

Tags: c#, list, listview, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I am trying to set the `ItemsSource` of a `ListView` from a nested `ObservableCollection` `List`.
While `HeaderGroups` are being created, `Items` in the groups are empty. Any idea?
Here is my code:

Classes:

```
public class TableDataGroup
    {
        public TableDataGroup(String imagepath, String championship, String tip)//, Color headergroupbgcolor,)
        {
            this.ImagePath = imagepath;
            this.Championship = championship;
            this.Tip = tip;
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<TableDataItem>();
        }

        public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
        public string Championship { get; private set; }
        public string Tip { get; private set; }
        
        public ObservableCollection<TableDataItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class TableDataItem
    {
        public TableDataItem(String imagepath, Color backgroundTipColour, String time, String teamone...)
        {
            this.ImagePath = imagepath;
            this.BackgroundTipColour = backgroundTipColour;
            this.Time = time;
            this.TeamOne = teamone;
            //...
        }

        public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
        public Color BackgroundTipColour { get; private set; }
        public string Time { get; private set; }
        public string TeamOne { get; private set; }
        //...
    }
```

Calls:

```
mainPageLoadViewModel.tableDataGroup = new ObservableCollection<TableDataGroup>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TableDataGroup tableDataGroup = new TableDataGroup("value", "value", "value","TIP");
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                tableDataGroup.Items.Add(new TableDataItem("flag",
                                                           backgroundtipcolor,
                                                           time,
                                                           teamone,
                                                           //...));
            }
            mainPageLoadViewModel.tableDataGroup.Add(tableDataGroup);
    }
    ItemsCollectionView.ItemsSource =  mainPageLoadViewModel.tableDataGroup;     ===> ObservableCollection<TableDataGroup>
```

xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding TableDataGroup}"
      IsGroupingEnabled="true" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackLayout Padding="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Padding="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Championship}" FontSize="15" TextColor="White"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="TIP" FontSize="15" TextColor="White"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <Grid Padding="10,5,5,10" BackgroundColor="Gray">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Time}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="13" TextColor="Black" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding TeamOne}" FontSize="13" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ScoreTeamOne}" FontSize="13" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="Gray" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="25" MinimumWidthRequest="25"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ScoreTeamTwo}" FontSize="13" Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="Gray" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="25" MinimumWidthRequest="25"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding TeamTwo}" FontSize="13" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="4" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Tip}" FontSize="13" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="5" BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill"></Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
                <!--<TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Description}"></TextCell>-->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: data needs to be grouped a certain way - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping#group-data

Comment: I was just looking at it, I am sure I am not grouping them right. I will have a look. Sorry if the question is wrong or bad

Comment: You can post that as an Answer if you want as it gave me the solution. Thank you